# how to integrate opencv in my project

Tags: android, opencv

I tried to integrate opencv library in my android project. I have these errors:

`jni/DetectionBasedTracker.cpp:5:23: error: opencv/cv.h: No such file or directory jni/DetectionBasedTracker.cpp:6:28: error: opencv/highgui.h: No such file or directory`

Any idea how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you reference OpenCV Library-2.4.4 in your project, in **Project Properties > Android > Library** ?

Have you included `<path_to_OpenCV4Android_sdk>/sdk/native/jni/include` in Project **Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > GNU C++**?